# React-Native image not uploading using Axios(MultiPart form data) via Content URI (react-native-camera)

Tags: laravel, react-native, axios

**There is the following information.**

**React Native version** `"react-native": "0.63.4"`

**I am using the below library for image capture using the device camera.**

`"react-native-camera": "^3.42.2"`

`import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera'`

**Below is my function, when capturing the image from the camera**

```
const onImagePressed = () => {
    const options = {
      title: 'Camera',
      takePhotoButtonTitle: 'Take Photo...',
      mediaType: 'photo',
      quality: 0.5,
      saveToPhotos: true,
    };

    launchCamera(options, (response) => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else {
        setImageObject({
          uri: response.uri,
          type: response.type,
          name: response.fileName,
        });
        // blobResponse(response);
      }
    });
  };
```

**For posting images or upload images, I am using Axios post request with the form data mentioned code below.**

**Payload Sample**

```
const payload = {
      filename: 'test file name',
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      uri: 'content://com.testapp.imagepickerprovider/cacheDir/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_a3c6bd5d-0855-4b57-aa4f-e29fa7676500.jpg',
    };
```

This is the same uri `'content://com.testapp.imagepickerprovider/cacheDir/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_a3c6bd5d-0855-4b57-aa4f-e29fa7676500.jpg'` that get from the launchCamera method as mentioned above.

**Form Data**

```
 var data = new FormData();
    data.append('images', payload);
```

**Axios Request**

```
export const API_INSTANCE = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});
```

The above function is a global function that exists in another file, I just posted it here.

```
await API_INSTANCE.post('/scan/product/save', data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
```

The question is, it sends the request to the server, but when I get the images key it becomes null or blank.

But the same thing, I tested using postman by putting a file then it will show the data.

API development in Laravel, So for better understanding if someone has server-related knowledge explicitly in Laravel then he or she can view that code as well.

**Below is my API.**

```
    public function store(Request $request): void
    {
       Log::debug($request->images);
    }
```

**Logs when posting using the above code.**

```
[2021-03-12 15:29:32] local.DEBUG:   
[2021-03-12 15:31:48] local.DEBUG:   
[2021-03-12 15:40:03] local.DEBUG:   
[2021-03-12 15:42:45] local.DEBUG:   
[2021-03-12 15:42:47] local.DEBUG:   
[2021-03-12 15:44:12] local.DEBUG:   
[2021-03-12 15:44:35] local.DEBUG:   
[2021-03-12 16:19:24] local.DEBUG:   
[2021-03-12 16:21:19] local.DEBUG:   
[2021-03-12 16:23:03] local.DEBUG:   
[2021-03-12 16:26:20] local.DEBUG:   
[2021-03-12 16:29:58] local.DEBUG:   
[2021-03-12 16:32:29] local.DEBUG:   
[2021-03-12 16:32:53] local.DEBUG:
```

**Logs when send request using postman**

```
[2021-03-12 17:04:53] local.DEBUG: /tmp/phpwgt3X7
```

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the following steps to solve the above problem.

- Using **Axios** to post the data on the server.

```
     import axios from 'axios';
     const BASE_URL = '';
     export const API_INSTANCE = axios.create({   baseURL: BASE_URL, });
```

- Using the above code as the default configuration for the application via connection.js file.
- Below code used for sending the data to the server.

```
import {API_INSTANCE} from '../config/connection';

 try {
          
      const dataToPost = createFormData(item); //createFormData is custom method
    
      const response = await API_INSTANCE.post(
        '/suburl',
        dataToPost,
      );
    
      if (response.status === 200) {
         //hanlde success case
      } else {
         //hanlde failed case
      }

   } catch (error) {
          
 }
```

**createFormData Definition**

```
const createFormData = (item) => {
    var data = new FormData();
    if (item && item.imageObject && item.imageObject.uri) {

//images are the key that accesses or get from the request input from the server-side.

      data.append('images', {
        name: item.imageObject.name,
        type: item.imageObject.type,
        uri:
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? item.imageObject.uri
            : item.imageObject.uri.replace('file://', ''),
      });
      delete item.imageObject;
    }
    //if some of the image object has empty uri then remove it as well.
    if (item && item.imageObject && !item.imageObject.uri) {
      delete item.imageObject;
    }
    //below code to append the all other key/value pair except image object. because we already append above.
    Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
      data.append(key, item[key]);
    });

    return data;
  };
```

- URI is the complete path that return in the result of
  **launchCamera** (which is provided by the `react-native-camera` library) method response, also mentioned earlier in the question part (can take help from there as well).